# how to show different route on google map for each salesperson

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, google-maps-api-3, polyline, maproute

I am working on a project where i need to track the salesperson's route of movement for a certain period (may span n days). I get locations stored from mobile device which i save in database using web service.

Now i have a multi-select drop-down for selecting salesperson(s). i pass the salesperson ids as comma separated values and get the latitude and longitude for selected salesperson(s) from database.

**Code is below.**

```
IList<RadComboBoxItem> Values = rcbSalesPersons.CheckedItems;
string Ids = String.Join(",", rcbSalesPersons.Items.Where(i => i.Checked).Select(i => i.Value).ToList());
List<SalespersonSpatialInfo> lstSpatialInfo = SalespersonSpatialInfo.getSpatialInfo(Ids, Session["StoreID"].ToString(),RadDatePickerFrom.SelectedDate.Value, RadDatePickerTo.SelectedDate.Value);
string jsonString;
if (lstSpatialInfo.Count > 0)
{
jsonString = JsonSerializer<List<SalespersonSpatialInfo>>(lstSpatialInfo);
ScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration(Page, "markers", jsonString);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "GoogleMap();", true);
            }
```

As i registered the javascript Markers array in source of the page, now i use following javascript function to plot the points on map and join them

```
function GoogleMap() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0][0].Latitude, markers[0][0].Longitude),
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var lat_lng = new Array();
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            for (i = 0; i < markers[0].length; i++) {
                var data = markers[0][i];
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
                lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map
                });
                latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
            }
            map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
            map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

            //***********ROUTING****************//

            //Initialize the Path Array
            var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

            debugger;

            //Initialize the Direction Service
            var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            //Set the Path Stroke Color
            var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#489615' });

            //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
            for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
                if ((i + 1) <= lat_lng.length) {
                    var src = lat_lng[i];
                    var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                    path.push(src);
                    poly.setPath(path);
                    service.route({
                        origin: src,
                        destination: des,
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
                    }, function (result, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                                path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

i get following json

```
    [
    {
        "DeviceID": null,
        "ID_SalesRep": 58,
        "Latitude": 22.693519,
        "LocationID": 1,
        "Longitude": 75.919796,
        "StoreID": "xyz",
        "TrackingTime": "/Date(1418246100000+0530)/"
    },
    {
        "DeviceID": null,
        "ID_SalesRep": 58,
        "Latitude": 22.701211,
        "LocationID": 2,
        "Longitude": 75.926846,
        "StoreID": "xyz",
        "TrackingTime": "/Date(1418246100000+0530)/"
    },
    {
        "DeviceID": null,
        "ID_SalesRep": 59,
        "Latitude": 22.750948,
        "LocationID": 3,
        "Longitude": 75.895411,
        "StoreID": "xyz",
        "TrackingTime": "/Date(1418246100000+0530)/"
    },
    {
        "DeviceID": null,
        "ID_SalesRep": 58,
        "Latitude": 22.705804,
        "LocationID": 4,
        "Longitude": 75.905024,
        "StoreID": "xyz",
        "TrackingTime": "/Date(1418246100000+0530)/"
    },
    {
        "DeviceID": null,
        "ID_SalesRep": 58,
        "Latitude": 22.711267,
        "LocationID": 5,
        "Longitude": 75.883073,
        "StoreID": "xyz",
        "TrackingTime": "/Date(1418246100000+0530)/"
    },
    {
        "DeviceID": null,
        "ID_SalesRep": 58,
        "Latitude": 22.718155,
        "LocationID": 6,
        "Longitude": 75.883802,
        "StoreID": "xyz",
        "TrackingTime": "/Date(1418246100000+0530)/"
    },
    {
        "DeviceID": null,
        "ID_SalesRep": 59,
        "Latitude": 22.747032,
        "LocationID": 7,
        "Longitude": 75.883727,
        "StoreID": "xyz",
        "TrackingTime": "/Date(1418246100000+0530)/"
    },
    {
        "DeviceID": null,
        "ID_SalesRep": 58,
        "Latitude": 22.726512,
        "LocationID": 8,
        "Longitude": 75.880881,
        "StoreID": "xyz",
        "TrackingTime": "/Date(1418246100000+0530)/"
    },
    {
        "DeviceID": null,
        "ID_SalesRep": 59,
        "Latitude": 22.718927,
        "LocationID": 9,
        "Longitude": 75.856036,
        "StoreID": "xyz",
        "TrackingTime": "/Date(1418246100000+0530)/"
    }
]
```

I also need to change the color of the marker and Polylines for different salespersons later when this is done.

Now the problem is, I need to show different routes for different salespersons but it shows the single route joining the locations for both the salespersons.
please ask for clarification if needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to show different routes for different salespersons but it shows the route."  Which route does it show?

Comment: @geocodezip see my edit in the bottom lines.

Comment: Where is the code that separates the points out by salesperson?

Comment: @geocodezip that's what i dont know how can i do that client side or should i do that server side instead and create different marker arrays for each salesperson. with this server side approach i dont know how many arrays created from server side. my JSON has an attribute called ID_SalesRep which tells me the salesperson id

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  The code posted doesn't work with the JSON posted.  I get a javascript error `Uncaught InvalidValueError: in property destination: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object` ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asfc6mxu/))

Comment: i can see the error, but that is not preventing to map and join the markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i get it working using the following server and client side logic

On server side i made n multiple arrays of locations belonging to each salesperson in resultset

**c#**

```
IList<RadComboBoxItem> Values = rcbSalesPersons.CheckedItems;
            string Ids = String.Join(",", rcbSalesPersons.Items.Where(i => i.Checked).Select(i => i.Value).ToList());
            //List<SalespersonSpatialInfo> lstSpatialInfo = SalespersonSpatialInfo.getSpatialInfo(Ids, Session["StoreID"].ToString(), new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1), DateTime.Now);
            List<SalespersonSpatialInfo> lstSpatialInfo = SalespersonSpatialInfo.getSpatialInfo(Ids, Session["StoreID"].ToString(), RadDatePickerFrom.SelectedDate.Value, RadDatePickerTo.SelectedDate.Value);
            var distinctSalespersons = lstSpatialInfo.Select(t => t.ID_SalesRep).Distinct().ToList();
            string jsonString;
            hdnMarkerArraySuffix.Value = "";
            if (lstSpatialInfo.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < distinctSalespersons.Count; i++)
                {
                    List<SalespersonSpatialInfo> lstMarkers = lstSpatialInfo.Where(o => o.ID_SalesRep == distinctSalespersons[i]).ToList();
                    jsonString = JsonSerializer<List<SalespersonSpatialInfo>>(lstMarkers);
                    ScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration(Page, "markers"+distinctSalespersons[i].ToString(), jsonString);
                    hdnMarkerArraySuffix.Value +=  distinctSalespersons[i] + ",";
                }
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "GoogleMap();", true);



            }
```

Note i use salesperson id suffix to diffrentiate the salesperson location arrays, i stored these ID suffix in hiddenfield to process them later when plotting markers and polylines.

the client side code to place markers and join them when multiple salespersons are selected from the multiselect dropdown
**Javascript**

```
 function GoogleMap() {

            var MarkerArrayNamesCSV = $('#<%=hdnMarkerArraySuffix.ClientID%>').val();
            if (MarkerArrayNamesCSV.charAt(MarkerArrayNamesCSV.length - 1) == ",") {
                MarkerArrayNamesCSV = MarkerArrayNamesCSV.slice(0, -1);
            }
            var MarkerArrayNames;
            if (MarkerArrayNamesCSV.indexOf(',') > 0) {
                MarkerArrayNames = MarkerArrayNamesCSV.split(',');
            }
            else {
                MarkerArrayNames = new Array();
                MarkerArrayNames.push(MarkerArrayNamesCSV);
            }

            var map;
            for (k = 0; k < MarkerArrayNames.length; k++) {

                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(window['markers' + MarkerArrayNames[k]][0][0].Latitude, window['markers' + MarkerArrayNames[k]][0][0].Longitude),
                    zoom: 10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                if (typeof map == 'undefined') {
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
                }

                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var lat_lng = new Array();
                var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (i = 0; i < window['markers' + MarkerArrayNames[k]][0].length; i++) {
                    var data = window['markers' + MarkerArrayNames[k]][0][i];

                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
                    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: map
                    });
                    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
                    (function (marker, data) {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                            infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                    })(marker, data);

                }

                //    map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
                //   map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

                //***********ROUTING****************//

                //Initialize the Path Array
                var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();



                //Initialize the Direction Service
                var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

                //Set the Path Stroke Color
                var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#489615' });


                //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
                try {
                    for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
                        if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
                            var src = lat_lng[i];
                            var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                            path.push(src);
                            poly.setPath(path);
                            service.route({
                                origin: src,
                                destination: des,
                                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
                            }, function (result, status) {
                                try {
                                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                                        for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                                            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (ex1) {
                                    alert('callback' + i);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            var src = lat_lng[i];
                            var des = lat_lng[i];
                            path.push(src);
                            poly.setPath(path);
                            service.route({
                                origin: src,
                                destination: des,
                                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
                            }, function (result, status) {
                                try {
                                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                                        for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                                            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (ex1) {
                                    alert('callback' + i);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (ex) {
                    alert(i);
                }

            }
        }
```

Notice i loop through the available marker arrays in the loop and then loop through the collection to place the markers and join them using polyline object

Though this can be very specific issue but i posted my solution in case someone faces this issue in future.